# CSV and Big Values

Tags: java, csv

I have string value.

The value is :

```
12345.123456789012345
```

I want to write this value to `csv` file from java.I use `OpenCSV` for this.
Here is the code.

```
    String csv = "D:\\denemehttp\\dene.csv";
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

    String [] country = "India#China#United States#12345.1234567890123456".split("#");

    writer.writeNext(country);

    writer.close();
```

But when I open the `csv` the value is :

```
12345.123456789
```

But it must be:

```
12345.123456789012345
```

And note that when I open the `csv` file with Notepad++ it show the true value:

```
12345.123456789012345
```

So what is the problem?

Edit:I found the solution.I try Apache POI and it works.You can set the cell type with APACHE POI and excell doesn't see the value as a number and doesn't format it.It writes the value as a string completely.

Comment: Which program do you use to open the CSV?

Comment: Excel will treat all large numbers as 64-bit floating point.

Comment: This is possibly just a formatting issue in Excel.  Try to adjust the formatting of the cell to show more precision.  You will also have to make the column wider!

Answer (score 3):

You mention that you opened up the CSV in two different applications.  The first one either clips it or formats it so you don't see the true value (eg. Excel).  Your program is correct.

If the application you are using is Excel which you are using to open, you need to enclose the value in double quotes (") before you write it.
The csv should look like:

```
"India","China","United States","12345.1234567890123456"
```

This is because Excel does not recognize the number with this amount of precision, it needs to be treated as a string.

Comment: I know my code is true.But when I double click and open the csv I want to see true value:12345.123456789012345

Comment: Then open it with a program that shows the full value.

Comment: You didn't tell us what application that is.

Comment: *But when I double click and open the csv I want to see true value* just change default csv open application to notepad++